# How can I retrieve the current route from the _Layout.cshtml file in my ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my _Layout.cshtml page, I have a list item in the main navigation bar.  I want to show a css class depending on the current route. For example, if the user is at www.website.com/Notifications, I want to add the class to the Notifications list item. This is my attempt. It does not work:

```
<li><a asp-page="/Notifications" class="@(<%=Url.RequestContext["id"]%>  == "Notifications" ? Html.Raw("selected-club") : Html.Raw(""))"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Notifications</a></li>
```

How can I get the current page ID from the layout file, considering that it doesn't have a page model?

Answer (score 4):

try the below codes that gets the current controller and action by RouteData values from the ViewContext

```
 <body>
    @{
        string controller = "";
        string action = "";

        if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] != null)
        {
            controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }

        if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] != null)
        {
            action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }

    <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        @if (controller.ToLower() == "home" && action.ToLower() == "about")
                        {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        }
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: you can use null propagator to save those 4 lines of code on top.

Comment: Hm.. I'm getting ``NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

MenuApp.WebPlatform.Application.Pages._Layout_View+<<ExecuteAsync>b__81_21>d.MoveNext() in _Layout.cshtml, line 63``